# Windows7 is not starting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

First I install Windows7 and then installed Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. Now when I restart machine, there is option to start windows, but sometime it is starting and sometime it displays blank screen.

I installed boot-repair on ubuntu and try to repair boot-loader with default(Recommended) option. Here is its report

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10983184/

Kindly help me to correct dual OS boot smoothly.

Thanks!

Comment: Try ` sudo update-grub` from the terminal

Comment: I've moved my post to answers section, you can accept it as the answer there to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo update-grub` from the terminal.